# Binding for a single event on an event emitter

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs

React components require events to receive status changes from other objects. To make the component reusable I would like to define the event type/name, which triggers the status changes, outside the component. So I was thinking about a class which binds the event emitter and the event type/name. The React component just needs to call .on, without any event type/name. Also it could make sense to merge more events into one. I haven't seen these generic classes in a framework, so I'm not sure if there is another design pattern and I just searched with the wrong keywords.

Is this the right way to handle events for generic React components?

Here an example, so you have a better idea:

```
var emitter = {};
_.extend(emitter, Backbone.Events);

var Component = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.props.update.on(function (text) {
      self.setState({text: text});
    });
    return {text: ''};
  },
  render: function () {
    return React.DOM.p({}, this.state.text != null ? this.state.text : '');
  }
});*

// this would require to know the event type/name in the component
//var component = React.createFactory(Component)({update: emitter});

var binding = new Event(emitter, 'label:changed');
var component = React.createFactory(Component)({update: binding});

// this would merge multiple events into a single one
/*var binding = Event.merge([
  new Event(emitter, 'label:changed'),
  new Event(emitter, 'label:deleted')]);*/

var component = React.createFactory(Component)({update: binding});
```

Comment: Did you mean to say React.js and not React - the PHP framework? If so, fix your tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with [Flux architecture](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#content)? It uses event emitters in [Stores](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#stores) that a [Controller-view](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#views-and-controller-views) can listen to. This is a really good example of what you're describing.

The Controller-view is a top level component that listens for new events and then passes the data down to lower level components via props.

Whether you implement Flux or not, Facebook has some good examples that answer your question in their [Todo List Example](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html#content).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I wasn't familiar with the Flux architecture. A store in that architecture looks very similar to my event class. If the store doesn't require any logic, because the payload can be forwarded without changes, it would be nice to generate the store on the fly. I created some helper classes to bring Backbone events into this architecture (I don't use the Backbone model stuff).

Here are my helper classes. I expected something like that to be part of Backbone or React.

[gist](https://gist.github.com/bergos/a68268bcb8743dda82fe)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but stores in a Flux pattern should have the majority of the logic.

Comment: Sure. But the stuff in the [switch statement](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-todomvc/js/stores/TodoStore.js#L125) is a recurring pattern. A very small store (smaller than the Todo example), which handles just a label change, like in my small example, the store doesn't have to keep the state and the payload can be forwarded. Also there is a `args` method in my classes (maybe not the best name), which can be replaced with a function that contains the store logic. At the end it's just replacing `switch/case` with `Event.bind`.